# On a horizontal plane, why does $F_N=W$?

Tags: forces, vectors

I keep seeing this definition everywhere, but I don't understand. The forces of the weight and the normal force are going in opposite directions, so shouldn't $F_N=-W$?

Comment: This probably just refers to their magnitudes, not their directions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this equation $F_N$ is the *magnitude* of the normal force, and $W$ is the *magnitude* of the weight. The forces are in opposite directions, yes, but their magnitudes are equal.

It would be correct to write this:

$$\vec{F}_N = -\vec{W}$$

because $\vec{F}_N$ refers to the full force vector, including its direction, not just the magnitude. (And similarly for $\vec{W}$.)

Comment: Ah, right! Then it makes perfect sense, thank you!